# Prime number check

Tags: recursion, f#, functional-programming, primes, primality-test

I'm having some issues with my prime number checker in F#. It doesn't seem to give the right results so I'm guessing I've screwed up the logic somewhere but I can't figure out where. The implementation is a simple brute forcing one so the logic isn't complicated and I've implemented similiar solutions using for loops in imperative languages before.

```
let rec isPrime iterator (n : int) = 
                            match iterator with
                            | 1 -> isPrime (iterator + 1) n
                            | a when a = n -> isPrime (iterator + 1) n
                            | _ -> match n % iterator = 0 with
                                    | true -> false
                                    | false -> isPrime (iterator + 1) n
```

Comment: Can you flesh out your question to explain how you call `isPrime`  initially (i.e. what the initial value of `iterator` is), and give an example of a wrong result it gives. Also, how can the code you've written ever return `true`?

Comment: The second case should evaluate to `true` instead of recursing further.. That was the error, thanks for helping me find it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already figured out in the comments, the problem is that the function should terminate and say `true` when the iterator reaches `n`. You can actually make it faster just by iterating up to square root of `n` or at least `n/2` because by the time you reach `n/2`, you know it will be a prime.

This kind of logic seems to be easier to write using `if` rather than `match` - although you can easily fix it by fixing the case in `match`, I'd probably write something like:

```
let rec isPrime iterator (n : int) = 
  if iterator = n / 2 then true
  elif iterator = 1 then isPrime (iterator + 1) n
  elif n % iterator = 0 then false
  else isPrime (iterator + 1) n
```

Also, you might not want to expose the `iterator` parameter to the user - you can write the code using a nested function which calls the loop starting with `iterator = 2` (and then you don't need the `iterator = 1` case at all):

```
let isPrime (n : int) = 
  let rec loop iterator = 
    if iterator = n/2 then true
    elif n % iterator = 0 then false
    else loop (iterator + 1)
  loop 2
```

Comment: Oh a nested recursive function, that is just genius! I was looking for a way to do optional parameters in F# to achieve the same thing, but a nested recursion is much smarter! The reason I have steered clear of using an `if` statement is that I read that using the use of pattern match is more idiomatic in F# but as you can tell I am completely new to F# so I might've misread or misunderstood :).